# Resources for IMO

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list, contest-math, online-resources

I am seeking an online resource or any book where I can find the questions of International Mathematical Olympiad questions chapter wise eg Number Theory problems grouped together.
Like [this](http://vnoi.info/index.php?option=com_voj&task=classify&site=spoj&filter=15&sort=1&limit=50&limitstart=0) site where we can get all the programming problems of [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.pl/) classified under different sections.
I have googled but didn't come across any such site. So I will greatly appreciate if anybody provides me some reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Art of Problem Solving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/resources.php)

Also check their forum, they have lots of extra materials:
[Forum](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/index.php?)

Answer (score 4):

This book introduces some basic concepts which are useful in solving problems in IMO.

Mathematical Olympiad Challenges

To explain each concept, the author uses a lot of math problems from IMO and so on.

I hope this is something you want!